# C# get Result from IF Statement

Tags: c#

I have a simple code like:

```
public IActionResult TestingSample(int A, int B)
    {
        if (A > B && B != 0)
        {
            int corr = 2 + A * B;
            string rescorr = corr.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            int wron = 2 * A + B;
            string reswron = wron.ToString();
        }
    }
```

From the code above, I want to add a result with: `rescorr + reswron`. So it becomes string result. How can I write the return value with string like that?

Really appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: But only 1 of those 2 values can ever be set.... so what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: From the logic of your code, that won't work, since you only use one string depending on your case. In what case do you want to combine the strings?

Comment: I have a hard time following your question. In your code either 'rescorr' is set OR 'reswron' is set. There is never a case when both are set. So 'rescorr + reswron' makes no sense. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably start by moving your string variables out of the if blocks

And then return the concatenated string.

```
public IActionResult TestingSample(int A, int B)
{
    string rescorr = string.Empty;
    string reswron = string.Empty;

    if (A > B && B != 0)
    {
        int corr = 2 + A * B;
        rescorr = corr.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        int wron = 2 * A + B;
        reswron = wron.ToString();
    }

    return rescorr + reswron;
}
```

Then you realise that only 1 of these will ever get set so we change the string assignments in to individual returns. We get get rid of the variables and the else block because that's now redundant too.

```
public IActionResult TestingSample(int A, int B)
{
    if (A > B && B != 0)
    {
        int corr = 2 + A * B;
        return corr.ToString();
    }

    int wron = 2 * A + B;
    return wron.ToString();

}
```

Comment: Yes, but in this case the combination will not be different from exactly one of them, so one could use a `return` statement in both cases to achieve the same.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
 public IActionResult TestingSample(int A, int B) => A > B && B != 0 
     ? $"{2 + (long)A * B}"   // "correct"
     : $"{2L * A + B}";       // "wrong"
```

here if  `A > B && B != 0` we have *correct* arguments and we return `2 + A * B`, othevise arguments are *wrong* and we return `2 + A * B`.

I've introduced `long` to fight with possible integer overflow (when, say, `A == 2_000_000`, `A = 1_000_000`)

Comment: Very compact but not so readable

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you have a single string result? if else will only return one

```
        string result = string.Empty;
        if (A > B && B != 0)
        {
            int cal = 2 + A * B;
            result = cal.ToString();
            return result;
        }
                
        int cal = 2 * A + B;
        result = cal.ToString();
        return result;
```